# Python3.8 Asyncio - Return Results from List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-3.8

I am really really struggling to figure out how to use asyncio to return a bunch of results from a bunch of AWS Lambda calls, here is my example.

My team owns a bunch of AWS accounts. For the sake of time, I want to run an async of AWS lambda functions to process the information of each account, and return the results. I'm trying to understand how I can create an async of sending a whole bunch of accounts quickly rather than doing it one at a time. Here is my example code.

```
def call_lambda(acct):

    aws_lambda = boto3.client('lambda', region_name='us-east-2')
    aws_payload = json.dumps(acct)

    response = aws_lambda.invoke(
    FunctionName='MyLambdaName',
    Payload=aws_payload,
    )

    return json.loads(response['Payload'].read())

def main():
    scan_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    accounts = []
    scan_data = []
    account_data = account_parser()

    for account_info in account_data:
        account_info['scan_time'] = scan_time

    for account in account_data:
        scan_data.append(call_lambda(account))
```

I am struggling to figure out how to do this in an asyncio style. I originally managed to pull it off using concurrent futures threadpoolexecutor, but I ran into some issues with performance, but here is what I had.

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50)
sg_data = executor.map(call_lambda, account_data)
```

So this worked, but not well, and I was told to do asyncio instead. I read these following articles but I am still just lost as to how to make this work. I know AWS Lambda itself is asynchronous, and should work fine without a coroutine.

The tl;dr is I want to kick off call_lambda(acct) for every single Dict in my List (account_data is a list of dictionaries) and then return all the results into one big list of Dict again. (this eventually gets written into an CSV, company policy issues for why not going into a database).

I have read the following, still confused...

https://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for aiobotocore?

Comment: Yes but it seems to work basically the same unless I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Lambda invocations are by default synchronous (RequestResponse), so you have to specify the InvocationType to Event. By doing this though you don't get your response to collate the account info you desire. Hence the desire to use async or something similar.

```
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
    LogType='None'|'Tail',
    ClientContext='string',
    Payload=b'bytes'|file,
    Qualifier='string'
)
```

I've not implemented async in lambda, but as alternate solution, if you can create an s3 file, then have each invocation of FunctionName='MyLambdaName' just update the file, you might get what you need that way.